# How to create a new column based on multiple conditions in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In pandas, How can I create a new column `B` based on a column `A` in `df`, such that:

- `B(i)=1` if `A_(i-1)-A_(i) >= 0` when`A_(i) <= 10`
- `B(i)=1` if `A_(i-1)-A_(i) >= 2` when`10 < A_(i) <= 20`
- `B(i)=1` if `A_(i-1)-A_(i) >= 5` when`20 < A_(i)`
- `B(i)=0` for any other case

However, the first `B_i` value is always two

Example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 (the first B_i) |
| 12 | 0 |
| 14 | 0 |
| 22 | 0 |
| 20 | 1 |
| 33 | 0 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 15 | 0 |
| 11 | 1 |

Comment: Shouldn't the item referent to A=20 be 1? According to the second condition

Comment: @brenodacosta correct! Just modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Pandas.shift` for creating `A_(i-1)` and use `Numpy.select` for checking multiple conditions like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,12,14,22,20,33,11,8,15,11]})
df['A_prv'] = df['A'].shift(1)

conditions = [
    (df.index==0),
    ((df['A_prv'] - df['A'] >= 0) & (df['A'].le(10))),
    ((df['A_prv'] - df['A'] >= 2) & (df['A'].between(10, 20, inclusive='right'))),
                                     # ^^^  10 < df['A'] <= 20 ^^^
    ((df['A_prv'] - df['A'] >= 5) & (df['A'].ge(20)))
]
choices = [2, 1, 1, 1]
df['B'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A  A_prv  B
0   5    NaN  2
1  12    5.0  0
2  14   12.0  0
3  22   14.0  0
4  20   22.0  1
5  33   20.0  0
6  11   33.0  1
7   8   11.0  1
8  15    8.0  0
9  11   15.0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way is to iterate trough the lines testing all the three conditions in a single-line `if-else` (as B(i) is 1 for all the true conditions).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,12,14,22,20,33,11,8,15,11]})
B = [2]
for i in range(1,len(df['A'])):
    newvalue = 1 if (df['A'][i-1]-df['A'][i]>=0 and df['A'][i]<=10) or (df['A'][i-1]-df['A'][i]>=2 and df['A'][i]>10 and df['A'][i]<=20) or (df['A'][i-1]-df['A'][i]>=5 and df['A'][i]>20) else 0
    B.append(newvalue)
df['B'] = B
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   5   2
1   12  0
2   14  0
3   22  0
4   20  1
5   33  0
6   11  1
7   8   1
8   15  0
9   11  1
```